# Why are the checkboxes absent under the Notify Operator Task?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I have several maintenance plans configured on a SQL 2008 R2 (10.50.6529).  When I remotely connect to it with SSMS 2008 R2 or SSMS 2016 to edit the notify operator task there is nothing listed, just blank.

If I RDP to the server and open SSMS locally, the expected checkboxes appear.

Why is this so?  Is this a just a one-off bug?

I thought, for the most part, that it didn't matter which version of SSMS you use.

[image: Remote SSMS]

[image: Local SSMS]

Comment: I have noticed a whole host of bugs as regards compatibility from SSMS 2016 and GUI usage. I haven't even been able to open up maintenance plans. Just looked and there's a known bug with maintenance plans and 2008 R2. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238486.aspx